# How to retrieve sheet data with formatting with Google Sheets Api V4

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-api

I want to retrieve only sheet's data from a spreadsheet with formatting.

How to achieve the same with Sheets Api?

Answer (score 17):

It isn't clear from your question just what kind of data you want to get.  Do you want to retrieve the values as they're formatted in the Google Sheets UI?  If so, then use the [`spreadsheets.values.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) API.  The parameter [valueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#query-parameters) controls how the values are formatted.  By default, the value is `FORMATTED_VALUE`, which will return the data as it's formatted in the Sheets UI.  Other values are listed on the [ValueRenderOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) reference page.  See the [Basic Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading) sample for more information.

If you want to retrieve the information about the format itself, use the [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) API.  Format information is in the response's [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData) (at `sheets.data.rowData.values`), in both the `userEnteredFormat` and `effectiveFormat` fields.

Comment: I want to get things like cell border, color, etc with the data in those cells

Comment: The latter part of my answer is what you're looking for then, using spreadsheets.get and the userEnteredFormat or effectiveFormat of the CellData.