# How to read Google Sheets text preserving font formatting

Tags: php, google-sheets

I'm considering using spreadsheets as a backed for simple website and tweaking reading google sheets data into html. When reading it, api prints only raw text.
Is there a way to read cell text with formatting (bold, italic, spaces, newlines etc.)?

```
$range = 'Sheet1!A1:A5';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (empty($values)) {
   print 'No data found.\n';
} else {
   foreach ($values as $row) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($row); $i++) {
          echo $row[$i];
          echo "<br/>";
      }
   }
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTg4I.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve sheet data with formatting with Google Sheets Api V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316877/how-to-retrieve-sheet-data-with-formatting-with-google-sheets-api-v4)

Comment: @Carlos M, yeah tried it. But it returns raw text no bold, italic or any formatting

Comment: That's not possible all you can get with spreadsheets get values is just the raw data...nothing else